# Accessing Firestore array in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore document with one field which is an array of strings.
I was able to access the value, but feel there must be an easier way and I'm doing something wrong.

```
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await docRef.get();
if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
  var optionsDoc = documentSnapshot.data()!;
  Map docMap = optionsDoc as Map;
  List<dynamic> counterList = docMap['counterValues'];
  List<String> counterCurrencies = counterList.map((s) => s as String).toList();
```

I have tried many variations including:

```
List<dynamic> counterList = documentSnapshot.data()['counterValues'];
```

This gives error `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.`

Edit: Note this is in state management not widget building.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this on my project inside a StreamBuilder:

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
    List<String> obrasUser = snapshot.data['obras'].cast<String>();
    ... //Build listview with the array content
  }
```

Comment: My bad, I should have specified this is from within state management. Updated

Answer (score 0):

I removed `Map docMap = optionsDoc as Map;` in your code and used optionMap in place of docMap and it worked.

Below is a working example.

```
// NB: confirm that your docRef is defined like mine.
DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> docRef =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('users/PClEKWNc1fG8zo0OWgHs');
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
    await docRef.get();
if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
  Map<String, dynamic> optionsDoc = documentSnapshot.data();
  // I removed 'Map docMap = optionsDoc as Map;'
  List<dynamic> counterList = optionsDoc['counterValues'];
  List<String> counterCurrencies =
      counterList.map((s) => s as String).toList();
  print(counterCurrencies);
}
```